# Replacing Celery Beat "CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE" with a dynamic source (database)

Tags: python, flask, celery

In the [Celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#beat-entries), the standard way to set the schedule of tasks is documented as hardcoding the schedule into the config file.

However, it also hints that this can be replaced with a custom backend. I see there is a dynamic, database driven option for Django but I'm using a simple Flask app to define my tasks.

Does anyone have a way to dynamically load the schedule, avoiding the need to restart the celery beat worker, either by dynamically pulling the schedule from a database or by reloading the schedule from a text file on a regular basis? Is it as simple as putting a `reload()` call around the schedule in a text file, perhaps even as its own scheduled celery task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE is just init/config sugar and the object is available from within a bound task at:

```
self.app.conf['CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE']
```

You might write a periodic task that pulls down new values from some back end.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the source object. I can work from there - thanks!

Comment: @PhilSheard can you share me your solution?